# using scroll and scrollto on an element

Tags: javascript

I know the jQuery methods `$.fn.scroll` and `$.fn.scrollTop` exist, as well as the window methods `scroll` and `scrollTop` but how would I use one of the native javascript functions on a specific element, like `document.getElementbyId('foo').scroll(function () { /* code */ });`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're looking for the scroll event so.

```
document.getElementById("foo").onscroll = function() { console.log("Hello world") }
```

Im not sure about scrolltop but i think it's a custom event from jquery.